# Linear-time maze exploration for finite automaton with pebbles?

Tags: graph-algorithms, automata-theory

[Blum and Kozen](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4567972) have shown that a robot with the computational capabilities of a finite automaton can visit all $n$ cells in a quadratic maze when the robot is equipped with two pebbles which it may place at any cell. Alternatively, $\Omega(\log(n))$ memory (and no pebbles) is also sufficient. They did not analyse their algorithm's runtime, but I suspect the execution requires $\Omega(n^2)$ steps without pebbles and $\Omega(n^3)$ with pebbles.

**My question:** Is linear-time exploration (under the same memory/pebble requirements) possible? If yes, how? If not, why not?

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you done a literature review of papers that cite Blum & Kozel, by searching on Google Scholar?  If there is an improvement on their result, it seems likely such a paper would cite them.

Comment: @D.W. I seem to have missed your comment, sorry. I did search for papers that cite Blum & Kozen, but I couldn't find any runtime improvements, which is why I turned to Stack Exchange. [This related paper](https://cpsc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/tr1188.pdf) from 1999 lists the task of finding an algorithm for visiting all cells of a maze that requires "substantially less than $O(n^2)$ moves" as an open question, so I'm not too optimistic. But at the same time, I haven't found any evidence that $O(n^2)$ is a lower bound for this type of problem.